# MySQL select query returns 250K+ results, delete query only deletes one?

Tags: mysql, sql, myisam

I don't understand this. I've dropped the table and recreated it multiple times, and it's the same every time. When I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `squares` WHERE MBRContains(PolyFromText('Polygon((-34 166, -34 171, -41 171, -41 166, -34 166))'), `coordinate`);
```

I'm returned over 250,000 results, which is correct. When I try and alter the query to delete this based on my where clause, like so:

```
DELETE FROM `squares` WHERE MBRContains(PolyFromText('Polygon((-34 166, -34 171, -41 171, -41 166, -34 166))'), `coordinate`);
```

MySQL sees fit to only delete a single row at a time. I'm not going to click 'Go' 250K+ times. Why is this? Here's the table structure...

```
`squares` (
   `square_id` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `ref_coord_lat` double(8,6) NOT NULL,
   `ref_coord_long` double(9,6) NOT NULL,
   `coordinate` point NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`square_id`),
   KEY `ref_coord_lat` (`ref_coord_lat`),
   KEY `ref_coord_long` (`ref_coord_long`),
   SPATIAL `coordinate` (`coordinate`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

If it's any use, this is MySQL 5.5.27, running on phpMyAdmin 3.5.2.2. Any ideas?

Comment: What`s your mysql client?

Comment: @Mihai, is this what you mean? `Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026`

Comment: I mean phpmyadmin,mysql workbench etc?

Comment: @Mihai, I'm using phpMyAdmin 3.5.2.2.

Comment: ...but the where conditions of the select and the delete you posted are different, so it is to be expected the number of results found would differ....

Comment: @Kzqai, Sorry about that. I was trying two different queries (both of which return in excess of 200K results). Both however only delete 1 row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try optimising your table squares.

EDIT:
Or add a limit:

```
DELETE FROM `squares` WHERE MBRContains(PolyFromText('Polygon((-42 175, -42 179, -48 179,     -48 175, -42 175))'), `coordinate`) LIMIT 10000;
```

Play with the limit parameter if you can.

Comment: Optimized, added a limit. Still no difference.

Answer (score 0):

That behavior strikes me as very odd, (if the client isn't slipping in a LIMIT 1 clause into the DELETE query.)

I can suggest a workaround. Use the SELECT query that returns the 250K+ rows, and use that as an inline view, and join back to the table to perform the delete.

```
DELETE t.*
  FROM `squares` t
  JOIN ( SELECT s.square_id
           FROM `squares` s 
          WHERE MBRContains(
                  PolyFromText(
                    'Polygon((-34 166, -34 171, -41 171, -41 166, -34 166))'
                  )
                  , s.`coordinate`
                )
       ) s
    ON s.square_id = t.square_id
```

(Test it as a SELECT first, replacing the DELETE keyword with SELECT.)

This doesn't answer the question of why this is happening (something peculiar with the behavior of the `MBRContains` or `PolyFromText` functions?) But it a possible workaround. The SELECT in the inline view should be materialized as a derived table (temporary MyISAM table),  and then the delete should work against that.  (Similar to creating a temporary table, inserting the results from a SELECT into it, and then referencing the table in another query.)